# typeid of enum changing when dynamically linked in matlab mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, boost, mex, typeid

I have a C++ library with a particular function that returns a `boost::any`, whose value type is a particular `enum` defined in a different included library. This normally works fine.

But when I link to my library dynamically from a Matlab mex file, `typeid(the_enum_t)` seems to be different for the things made in my library and those made in the caller, in that it doesn't compare `==`. Since I'm actually using [`flann`](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/), whose version of `boost::any` performs a check based on `type_info::==`, this makes everything break. Static linking works fine, but that's kind of a pain here, and I'd really rather have it work either way.

I thought `type_info::==` was supposed to work consistently across library boundaries. Does this have to do with how Matlab dynamically loads libraries from mex?

---

Here's some code to reproduce this (also available in easy-to-download form, with a makefile, in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3121435)).

First, a stand-in for the library that defines the enum (`flann`):

```
namespace library {
    enum the_enum_t { el_one, el_two, el_three };
}
```

Now a proxy for my library, `stubby.hpp`:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include "the_enum.hpp"
boost::any the_function();
```

And its implementation `stubby.cpp`:

```
#include "stubby.hpp"
boost::any the_function() {
    return boost::any(library::el_two);
}
```

Finally, test code `test.cpp`, which is compiled with `-DNO_MEX` for a standalone and not for a mex file:

```
#include "stubby.hpp"
#include <boost/any.hpp>

#ifdef NO_MEX
#include <cstdio>
using std::printf;
int main() {
#else
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray **plhs, int nrhs, const mxArray **prsh) {
#endif
    boost::any val_any = the_function();
    printf("%s (equal: %d)\n",
            val_any.type().name(),
            val_any.type() == typeid(library::the_enum_t));
}
```

I get the expected output

```
N5flann17flann_algorithm_tE (equal: 1)
```

from each of

```
$ g++ -o test{,.cpp} -DNO_MEX libstubby.a && ./test      
$ g++ -o test{_s,.cpp} -DNO_MEX libstubby.so && ./test_s
$ ln -sf test{,_s}.cpp && mex test_s.cpp libstubby.a && matlab -r test
```

But dynamically linking a mex file doesn't work:

```
$ mex test.cpp libstubby.so && matlab -r test
N5flann17flann_algorithm_tE (equal: 0)
```

I see this same behavior on

- Matlab R2011b and R2011a, OSX 10.7, Apple gcc 4.2.1
- Matlab R2011b, CentOS 5.7, gcc 4.1.2
- Matlab R2010a, Ubuntu 11.04, gcc 4.4.5

The weird thing is that I could've sworn it worked a few months ago, but maybe I just did a bad job of testing.

Obviously I can get around this by static linking. But why is this happening? Does it have something to do with the way Matlab loads mex files and their libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost has a workaround for this issue; see https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/754

It's possible that boost is failing to enable the workaround.  Try passing compiler flag `-DBOOST_AUX_ANY_TYPE_ID_NAME` per the patch on that ticket.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Boost.Any was actually already working, but since I was only testing with `type_info`, I didn't see the workaround in place. `flann::any` doesn't include that workaround and was actually causing crashes because of that, I just simplified the test code too much.